# using REGXP in mysql to search and replace

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to search and replace the "http" protocol to "https" in certain domains in my MySql DB in a "links" table that contains urls only.

I would have used the REPLACE function if I was to change ALL the urls to "https".
but because it's certain domains I have to use REGEXP:

```
SELECT long_url 
FROM links 
WHERE long_url REGEXP '^http\:\/\/(www|academic|www3)\.?domain\.com'
```

so so far I got to the searching stage.
I've looked in the documents and as of now I see no way to do the replace with the result I got from the sql query.

please note I only have access to the MySql database, I don't have PHP or anything to run anything smarter than SQL queries.

Comment: MariaDB has `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Comment: thanks but if it's not something MySql standard - it's not relevant

Comment: Maybe not relevant to you, but other readers may find it useful -- especially those who already have, or could switch to, MariaDB.  Note that I gave it as a Comment, not an Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has no regex replacement support (outside perhaps of a UDF which you might write yourself).  But we can use `REGEXP` in the `WHERE` clause of your update:

```
UPDATE links
SET long_url = REPLACE(long_url, 'http://', 'https://')
WHERE long_url REGEXP '^http\:\/\/(www|academic|www3)\.?domain\.com';
```

Comment: As @TimBiegeleisen mentioned, `MySQL` has a nice collection of [UDF](http://www.mysqludf.org/) where there is a `REGEX` related one called [PREG](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme).

Comment: Tim's query is the answer for me. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Since the matched string always starts with http: you can do the following:

```
SELECT 'https' || SUBSTRING(long_url , 4)
FROM links 
WHERE long_url REGEXP '^http\:\/\/(www|academic|www3)\.?openu\.ac\.il'

UPDATE links
SET long_url = 'https' || SUBSTRING(long_url , 4)
WHERE long_url REGEXP '^http\:\/\/(www|academic|www3)\.?openu\.ac\.il'
```

I'm not aware of any mysql regex replace function.

Comment: what does "||" do ?

Comment: @john_black - `||` is the same as `OR` for logical operations:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or ; it is _incorrect_ here.  The correct syntax involves `CONCAT(...)`